# Access AWS S3 from Lambda within VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

Overall, I'm pretty confused by using AWS Lambda within a VPC. The problem is Lambda is timing out while trying to access an S3 bucket. The solution seems to be a VPC Endpoint.

I've added the Lambda function to a VPC so it can access an RDS hosted database (not shown in the code below, but functional). However, now I can't access S3 and any attempt to do so times out.

I tried creating a VPC S3 Endpoint, but nothing has changed.

**VPC Configuration**

I'm using a simple VPC created by default whenever I first made an EC2 instance. It has four subnets, all created by default.

**VPC Route Table**

```
_Destination - Target - Status - Propagated_

172.31.0.0/16 - local - Active - No

pl-63a5400a (com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3) - vpce-b44c8bdd - Active - No

0.0.0.0/0 - igw-325e6a56 - Active - No
```

**Simple S3 Download Lambda:**

```
import boto3
import pymysql
from StringIO import StringIO

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3Obj = StringIO()

    return boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('marineharvester').download_fileobj('Holding - Midsummer/sample', s3Obj)
```

Comment: VPC S3 endpoints require route table configuration and security policy configuration. You would need to show how you have configured those settings if you want help with that. The documentation is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html Alternatively you could add a NAT Gateway to the VPC which would give the Lambda function access to everything outside the VPC, not just the S3 service.

Comment: this is vpc configuration issue. configure any one sbunet assosiatio with nat gateway on route table. r u still looking on issue?

Comment: I've added some information on the VPC configuration. I figured that would be where the issue is, but the VPC is largely a black box to me. I don't know what to check with it to see what might be misconfigured.

Comment: If your requirements allow for it, is preferable to use anything other than a NAT gateway for accessing s3 due to the costs associated are higher than the alternatives: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/choosing-your-vpc-endpoint-strategy-for-amazon-s3/ (gateway is free)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

With boto3, the S3 urls are *virtual* by default, which then require internet access to be resolved to region specific urls.  This causes the hanging of the Lambda function until timeout.

To resolve this requires use of a `Config` object when creating the client, which tells boto3 to create *path* based S3 urls instead:

```
import boto3 
import botocore

client = boto3.client('s3', 'ap-southeast-2', config=botocore.config.Config(s3={'addressing_style':'path'}))
```

Note that the region in the call must be the region to which you are deploying the lambda and VPC Endpoint.

Then you will be able to use the `pl-xxxxxx` prefix list for the VPC Endpoint within the Lambda's security group, and still access S3.

Here is a working [CloudFormation script](https://github.com/gford1000-aws/lambda_s3_access_using_vpc_endpoint) that demonstrates this.  It creates an S3 bucket, a lambda (that puts records into the bucket) associated to a VPC containing only private subnets and the VPC Endpoint, and necessary IAM roles.

Comment: Is there a similar setting for the node.js aws-sdk? I see [s3ForcePathStyle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: There is a typo in your import statement.  Should be:

`import botocore`

Then the next line should work as expected.

Comment: typo in the snippet, the single quotes should be closed in `'ap-southeast-2'`.

Comment: what to do while using the `boto3.Session()`? How to pass this parameter?

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 89):

There is another solution related to VPC endpoints.

On AWS Console, choose VPC service and then Endpoints. Create a new endpoint, associate it to s3 service

[image: VPC S3 endpoint selection]

and then select the VPC and Route Table.

Then select access level (full or custom) and it will work.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, spent a whole day with this issue. It fixed!!!

Comment: Saved me so much headache after I added my Chalice function to the VPN and S3 just stopped connecting.

Comment: I actually overlooked this answer at first because I thought it was related to creating a new VPC when in reality it is related to **endpoints** The only thing I would add to this answer is that I chose the `gateway` option instead of the `interface` option as the VPC pricing page explicitly indicates no cost  of the VPC endpoint gateway (not sure about the interface). Note, the gateway and interface will both have the same service name. In my case that was "com.amazonaws.us-east-2.s3"

Comment: This is what did it for me too, nice and simple with no changes to my `s3.get_object` calls, and I can still reach the files using the `https://` url as well.

Comment: What Endpoint Url are you then using? I've added the Gateway Endpoint in my VPC, added the VPC to my lambda, still I'm getting a timeout, when the s3 sdk tries to access `s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: I create an interface endpoint and it allowed me to access my bucket in ec2, but not in lambda.
I had to create an additional gateway endpoint to fix my lambda.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: wish I could find "access level (full or custom)"

Comment: I have tried the above same method for default VPC. It's working fine. Keep in mind to select the s3 service name as well as the router table ( default ) in order to work correctly.

Answer (score 9):

There's another issue having to do with subnets and routes that is not addressed in the other answers, so I am creating a separate answer with the proviso that all the above answers apply.  You have to get them all right for the lambda function to access S3.

When you create a new AWS account which I did last fall, there is no route table automatically associated with your default VPC (see Route Tables -> Subnet Associations in the Console).

So if you follow the [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpce-gateway.html#vpc-endpoints-routing) to create an Endpoint and create a route for that Endpoint, no route gets added, because there's no subnet to put it on.  And as usual with AWS you don't get an error message...

What you should do is create a subnet for your lambda function, associate that subnet with the route table and the lambda function, and then rerun the Endpoint instructions and you will, if successful, find a route table that has three entries like this:

```
Destination     Target
10.0.0.0/16     Local
0.0.0.0/0       igw-1a2b3c4d
pl-1a2b3c4d     vpce-11bb22cc
```

If you only have two entries (no 'pl-xxxxx' entry), then you have not yet succeeded.

In the end I guess it should be no surprise that a lambda function needs a subnet to live on, like any other entity in a network.  And it's probably advisable that it not live on the same subnet as your EC2 instances because lambda might need different routes or security permissions.  Note that the GUI in lambda really wants you to have two subnets in two different AZs which is also a good idea.

Comment: To create an endpoint in the AWS Console go to VPC Dashboard > Endpoints

Comment: I think this will not work , igw route will be taken , but that will drop  ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html#vpc-endpoints-routing

Answer (score 8):

The cause of my issue had been not properly configuring the Outbound Rules of my security group. Specifically, I needed to add Custom Protocol Outbound Rule with a destination of pl-XXXXXXXX (the S3 service. The actual value was provided by the AWS Console).

Comment: can you give example how to do this since even I am facing same issue

Comment: The `pl-xxx` looks like a prefix list, as described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html#vpc-endpoints-basics and can be found on the command line with `aws ec2 describe-prefix-lists`.

Comment: In the end I just made a security group just for that lambda function: `aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name my-lambda --description 'Good luck' --vpc-id vpc-123456`  I applied that group and no other.  The egress rules are the only ones that matter.  If you give none, everything is permitted.  I was not very happy with that but the code is small and auditable and I could not get the tight controls to work.  If the code becomes more complex I will have to revisit this.

Comment: This should work if you have outbound rules on your security groups set to 0.0.0.0/0 for all ports, right? Because the `download_fileobj` is still just hanging

Comment: Superb!! Thanks I also had VPC subnets and route table configured perfectly but forgot that security gateway can block it, that for pointing it out.

Comment: Which port should I open for the s3 prefix list? Is it the 443 port?

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add one other answer amongst the others, which might affect those running functions with slow cold start times.

I'd followed all the instructions about setting up a gateway for S3, but still it didn't work. I created a test Node.js function which simply listed the buckets - I verified that this didn't work without the S3 gateway, but did once the gateway was established. So I knew that part of things was working fine.

As I was debugging this I was changing the timeout of the function to ensure the function was updated and I was using the latest version of the code when invoking and testing.

I'd reduced the timeout to 10s, only it turned out my function needed more like 15s on cold boot. **Once I'd increased the timeout again, it worked.**

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer from [Luis RM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57742313/3800170), this is a construct that can be used in CDK:

```
 const vpcEndpoint = new ec2.GatewayVpcEndpoint(this, 'S3GatewayVpcEndpoint', {
      vpc: myVpc,
      service: { name: 'com.amazonaws.us-west-1.s3' },
    })

    const rolePolicies = [
      {
        Sid: 'AccessToSpecificBucket',
        Effect: 'Allow',
        Action: [
          's3:ListBucket',
          's3:GetObject',
          's3:PutObject',
          's3:DeleteObject',
          's3:GetObjectVersion',
        ],
        Resource: ['arn:aws:s3:::myBucket', arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*'],
        Principal: '*',
      },
    ]
    rolePolicies.forEach((policy) => {
      vpcEndpoint.addToPolicy(iam.PolicyStatement.fromJson(policy))
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

To access S3 from within the Lambda function which is within a VPC, you can use a Natgateway (a much expensive solution in comparison to the VPC endpoint ). If you have two private subnets within the VPC, (where subnets are having a route to a NAT gateway ) and associate them with the Lambda, it can access the S3 bucket like any Lambda which are outside the VPC.
Gotchas

1. If you associate a public subnet with the Lambda expect it to work, it will not.
2. Make sure your security group is in place to accept ingress.

This approach will make any service available in the internet accessible to the Lambda function . For detailed steps you can follow this blog https://blog.theodo.com/2020/01/internet-access-to-lambda-in-vpc/

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to access S3 from within private subnet in a VPC

- NAT Gateway
- Gateway Endpoint
- Interface Endpoint

I assume that you don't want to use NAT Gateway.

If you're using Gateway endpoint - you don't need to change the endpoint that you connect to S3. But if you're using interface endpoint, you need to update the s3 endpoint.

There is a detailed step-by-step guide on doing the same here - https://www.cloudtechsimplified.com/aws-lambda-vpc-s3/