# AWS Lambda unable to GET a file from S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, lambda

Hi I have a lambda (python3.6) below that is unable to read a file from S3, even though the lambda is in a role that has unfettered permissions for S3 (IAM policy below).

The Lambda simply attempts to retrieve a file from S3 and write it to a temporary location.  However it blocks on calling `s3.Bucket()` and times out (even with a timeout in the minutes).

What's really weird is that it's timing out without any exception, and not rejecting the call to `s3.Bucket()` with some kind of permission error.

This is pretty basic, but I'm at a loss to get this sorted out.

```
import boto3
from botocore import exceptions

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  key = event['image']
  bucket = event['bucket']
  tempfile = '/tmp/%s-%s' % (bucket, key)
  print('(p) bucket: %s::%s' % (bucket, key))
  print('(p) tempfile: %s' % tempfile)
  s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
  print('(p) resource intiialized')
  try:
    b = s3.Bucket(bucket) 
    print('(p) bucket info: %s [%s]' % (b.name, b.creation_date))
    b.download_file(prefixed_key, tempfile)
    print('(p} file downloaded to %s' % tempfile)
  except exceptions.ParamValidationError as e:
    return {"statusCode": 400, "body": 'ParamValidationError: [%s]' % e}
  except exceptions.ClientError as e:
    message = '[%s]: [%s]' % (e.response['Error']['Code'], e.response['Error']['Message'])
    return {"statusCode": e.response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'], "body": message}
  print('(p) image downloaded from s3 and stored at: %s' % tempfile)
  return None
```

IAM Policy that the role has is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Example logs:

```
22:42:43
START RequestId: 61c60167-839d-11e7-97b1-a772bbde2609 Version: $LATEST
START RequestId: 61c60167-839d-11e7-97b1-a772bbde2609 Version: $LATEST
22:42:43
(p) bucket: my_bucket::my_key
22:42:43
(p) tempfile: /tmp/my_bucket/my_key
22:42:43
(p) resource intiialized
22:43:13
END RequestId: 61c60167-839d-11e7-97b1-a772bbde2609
END RequestId: 61c60167-839d-11e7-97b1-a772bbde2609
```

Comment: Do you mean the Lambda function itself is timing out? Did you increase the function timeout from the default of 3 seconds? Is it running in a VPC with no outbound network connectivity?

Comment: I've set the function timeout to be as much as 2 minutes, and the Lambda itself times out.  I've added some log output to illustrate.

Comment: What are the details of the exception messages? You're not getting the "image downloaded" message, so your function must be returning before that -- and the only returns in that sequence are in the exception clauses.

Comment: There are no exception messages.  Even if the timeout setting is in the minutes, it neither returns nor completes execution.

Comment: Tried this to no avail:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39797802/87408

Comment: Works fine here (until it hits the coding bug with uninitialized prefixed_key). Can you start again with a new Python 3.6 Lambda function and make it really simple (just get S3 resource and call Bucket constructor for hard-coded bucket name)?

Comment: You included an "S3 bucket policy". Did you mean the IAM role that the Lambda assumes?

Comment: sorry yes that's a typo -- it's an IAM role's policy.  Will try recreating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was narrowed down to a misconfiguration of the VPC.  I simply configured it to run outside of a VPC as I don't need that for now, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I had not installed a [VPC gateway endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html).  Although my own instances in my subnets in the VPC could access the S3 URLS, the Lambda instances could not.  This was fixed by adding a VPC gateway with default options to allow my subnets to use it.  Now my Lambda instances are able to access S3.
This is a free option as compared to using a NAT gateway.

PS you need to make permissions were granted on S3 object.  I made it public readable which is probably a bit too wide.