# Python AWS boto3.client("s3") operations time out (such as .get_object()) in lambda function

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm setting up a lambda function that pulls file objects from s3. I kept getting timeout errors, and after investigation it seems like the place where the code hangs is where I call s3.get_object(...), where s3 = boto3.client('s3')

It looks like all code involving boto3 has issues, because the aws secrets manager (uses boto3.session) also hangs.

I wondered if it was a credentials issues, but thought it wasn't likely since it's running from within a lambda function.

```py
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def handler(event, context):
    """
    This function fetches content from MySQL RDS instance
    """
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    body_json = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['body'])
    bucket = body_json["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(body_json["Records"][0]["s3"]['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')

    #Everything runs up to this line, and hangs from here on out
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
```

I think the strangest part is that everything about my code worked and functioned until a few hours ago, and I had no issues with s3. Not really sure what changed since I didn't change any of the lambda code...

Comment: Maybe you changed the lambda's IAM policy? This could explain why it stopped working without changing code

Comment: See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524727/can-not-access-s3-via-vpc-endpoint-in-lambda). When the lambda is in a VPC then it cannot connect to the S3 without proper settings.

Comment: How big is the object you are wanting to access? Have you tried increasing the timeout value of the Lambda function? (What is the timeout currently set to?)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The object is about 67 kb, and yep, I tried increasing to 8 minutes and that still timed out.

Comment: Is the Lambda function configured to use a VPC?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yup, it's configured to do so. I had the correct (or so I think) permissions because it made connections earlier.

Comment: So the issue was closely related to what @Lamanus posted, if you see op's answer in that post he says things about using 2 private vpc's only which solved my issue. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to give your lambda permissions to use s3.

[This might help](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-execution-role-s3-bucket/)

Comment: I gave the function access to all s3 permissions, but I'm wondering if there's a way permissions may conflict? I have FullVPCAccess, FullS3Access, FullSQSAccess, and AWSSecretsManager allowed right now

Comment: @user11875807 Did you found any solution?