# How to access s3 from a serverless lambda function?

Tags: amazon-s3, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless, serverless-architecture

I have a serverless lambda function that cannot access s3 bucket. I get `Connect timeout on endpoint URL:` error.

This Lambda is associated with a VPC and I have already given s3 permission.

```
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        # todo: too broad, just for illustration
        - s3:*
      Resource:
        # todo: too broad, just for illustration
        - arn:aws:s3:::*
```

Comment: You need to create an S3 VPC endpoint

Comment: Almost a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39779962/495455

Answer (score 0):

After adding S3 VPC endpoint this issue is resolved.