# 504 timeout accessing S3 from Lambda with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

This is not an issue with the size of the files, the files are very small. It works perfectly where running locally, but not in the Lambda.

I attached a `bucket-access` policy to Lambda role `mylambdarole`:
[image]

which looks like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I also added a permission policy to `my-bucket`:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Lambda permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXX843121XXX:role/mylambdarole"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Lambda is in a VPC, but I think this shouldn't be a problem as I have a route to internet gateway:

[image]

The endpoint uses `boto3`, which for example loads data from the bucket:

```py
def get_user_data_from_bucket(user_id: str):
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, region_name=REGION)
    try:
        data = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=f"{user_id}/user_data.json")
        return json.loads(data["Body"].read())
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response["Error"]["Code"] == "NoSuchKey":
            return {}
        raise e
```

I also tried adding `config=Config(s3={'addressing_style':'path'})` to the client, but it didn't solve the issue.

As I said, it works when running the server locally. However, when the endpoint for downloading data is called, there is no error response, only after some time I get `504: Endpoint request timed out`. Accessing RDS from the same Lambda function works just fine.

Comment: Why are you using `aws_access_key_id` & `aws_secret_access_key` when using a Lambda execution role?

Comment: Well I need it to use it locally and I assume the lambda just sets those environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You configured your Lambda function to connect to a VPC public subnet. Lambda functions connected to a public subnet cannot access the internet. Even though it routes to the IGW, the Lambda does not have a public IP, and so its outbound packets are dropped at the IGW. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992085/why-cant-an-aws-lambda-function-inside-a-public-subnet-in-a-vpc-connect-to-the).

Re-configure the Lambda function to connect to a private subnet.

Also, there's no need for that S3 bucket policy (use the IAM role) or the manual credentials (use the IAM role).

Comment: Thank you. Based on the answer you linked I looked at VPC endpoints and followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/57742313/13504606, which solved the issue.